# How can I avoid writing a loop when allocating orders to a stock impacted by the orders?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I have three tables in my database representing product storage, order items, and shipments:

```sql
CREATE TABLE storage (
    product_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    storage1 INT,
    storage2 INT
);

CREATE TABLE order_items (
    order_id INT,
    product_id INT,
);

CREATE TABLE shipment_product (
    shipment_id INT,
    product_id INT,
    location VARCHAR(50), -- Represents either 'storage1' or 'storage2'
);
```

Given this basic schema, I want to allocate shipments based on the following criteria:

- If an order's entire quantity can be sent from one location, prefer storage1.
- If an order can only be shipped from storage2, then use storage2.
- Split between both storages in last recourse.
- No allocation should reduce stock below zero in any storage.

For the stock constraint, I have a trigger set up to ensure stock does not go negative.

The challenge here is to process all orders and generate the necessary shipment_product rows without looping through each order : I cannot think of a good way to allocate all my open orders while keeping track of the state of stock that is impacted by this allocations.

I understand loops are bad and should be avoided.

How can I achieve this in a set-based approach? My question is really about finding a way to integrate the stock constraint to my solution, not so much the implementation of the split between stocks.

Comment: To allow us to do your work, at least provide a complete test case with sample values desired result. Ideally in a fiddle. Are there FK constraints? Always disclose your Postgres version, and mention rough cardinalities.

Comment: I'll work on rewording the question, providing more context and a minimum working example, as well as the working but ugly UDF-based solution I have. 

However I am not sure how I should take your "do your work" bit when precisely I am not asking for anyone to do my work but to help me think about my problem. Maybe I'm seeing passive-aggressiveness where I shouldn't... At any rate I appreciate the value experienced programmers like you bring to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which DB youre on. But you can try to select all **order_items** create a **row_number() over (partition by product_id)**. And then join the **shipment_product** and **storage** tables.

To get the location you can use a simple **case when row_number <= storage.storage1 then 'storage1' else 'storage2' end as location**.

If you need a second storage limit for storage2 then you can just extend the **case when row_number <= storage.storage1 then 'storage1' when row_number+storage.storage1 <= storage.storage2 then 'storage2' else null end as location**

I guess you should write in with CTEs, to keep the overview.

Comment: I've given this a bit of thought and I don't think it really works because you can miss possible allocations if the row_id is superior to storageX but the previous rows were not allocated to storageX.